# calling R code from within VBscript

Tags: r, vbscript

is it possible to execute R code with vbscript and return an array back to the vbscript calling function?

I'm trying to forecast daily transactions in R, which will return an array of forecasted values. I will then use vbscript to process this array.

thank you for any help or feedback